# How to create a page specific link

Tags: html, css

I've created an icon and wondered how to make it page specific. I'm using WordPress so the html is implemented through a html widget on the home page. But when the user navigates to a different page, I'd like the link to share that page to social media rather than, as currently, the site page.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="custom_html-21" class="widget_text widget widget_custom_html">
  <div class="textwidget custom- html-widget">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://4309.co.uk" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <div class="containercross">
        <div class="cross1">
          <div class="cross2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) . {
   #custom_html-21 {
      position: absolute;
      height: 0px;
      top: -8px !important;
      left: 90%;
      margin-left: -46px;
   }
}
#custom_html-21 {
   position: absolute;
   height: 0px;
   top: -5px;
   left: 90%;
   margin-left: -46px;
}
.containercross {
   left: 0px;
   top: 20px;
}
.cross1 {
   height: 20px;
   width: 5px;
   background-color: black;
   margin-left: 50px;
}
.cross2 {
   height: 20px;
   width: 5px;
   background-color: black;
   margin-left: 50px;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

So if the user is on the homepage and choses  to share the homepage, then they press on the link in the homepage and that shares the homepage to social media. But I want to make it so that if a user is on another page, they press the same icon and it links to social media in the same way, but instead of sharing the homepage it shares the page the user is on.

Easiest to see on mobile [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: I create a demo with your code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/BaKxWYq).

Comment: Substantially, you want something like a Facebook's Share Button?

Comment: Ok. If its the same difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can do this:

```
$currentPageUrl = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$link = 'https://www.example.com?share=' . $currentPageUrl;
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?=$link?>" target="_blank">Share this page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i implement it? Where would I place the php and html? Amd could I implement it as it is? As in "$link" as the link?

Comment: I'm not an expert on WordPress. Maybe you have to implement it in the pages' template(s).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: @Newstack If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.